# Windows Phone C# - Get Real Time

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, time, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there any way to get real world time into my application? (We can only retrieve such a high accuracy time on internet, so I need a method like this, which returns the real clock from internet)

Comment: SNTP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Comment: Okay.... what is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: I just simply tried this to retrieve the beginning time.  Time=DateTime.Now.ToString();

Comment: Please comment why none of NTP, getting time from response of random servers (i.e. via Last-modified header) and having own server to provide time does not work for you. It is very unclear what type of solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.UtcNow` returns the UTC time which is independent of time zone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx

To use Googles time; send an http get to https://www.google.com/search?q=utc+now&oq=utc+now&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j60j0j60j62.1138&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

parse out the value at `<div class="vk_bk vk_ans">1:31 AM</div>` basically; `where element.class == "vk_bk vk_ans" get element.innerHTML`

If you're interacting with your own server just have it send the time in ticks back to the client. Btw, even if you do this someone who really wants to cheat your system will be able to do it.

Comment: I know it, but it returns your phones time by restoring it into GMT +0 if you use GMT +X timezone. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KeremAytaç The user could break it by changing the system time. If you want to use googles time I'm adding an edit.

Comment: +1 UtcNow should be fine for most practical cases - phone time is generally synchronized already. If user really wants to cheat - asking server time will not be better (and probably easier to change) than local phone's time. Note that you don't need to parse HTTP response - "Last-modified" header on most pages contains "current" time.

Comment: No Alexei, I'm disagree with you, I can easily cheat by changing my phone's time when I use datetime.UtcNow. Just setting my clock, buum, my application now uses this changed and non-synced time. :)

Answer (score 1):

If time spent on a task is important, keep all the times at the server.  Have a method that starts the time and it should return the expiration time.  The user then submits the answer and if it's after the expected time, reject it.

Comment: Is there no way to get Windows server time? or any time resides on web?

Comment: @KeremAytaç use this url and parse it out of the response https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=utc+now&oq=utc+now&gs_l=hp.3..0l3j0i10.1646.2461.0.2622.7.7.0.0.0.0.101.490.6j1.7.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.NBgZDK7tr8E&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41934586,d.cGE&fp=cb92457a1274b65a&biw=1426&bih=1158 but that is ridiculous. Just use my suggestion instead.

Comment: I see your suggestion, but as I know, it returns your phone's time. And if you change your phone time, this time will be changed as well. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KeremAytaç: The entire point of this answer is that you shouldn't be keeping any time value that matters at the client.  When they query the server to start the "session," give them the timeframe that it must be completed in.  If you do this, you never have to worry about them altering the time to being with.

Comment: But I'm quite newbie on windows phone development. If I try to submit a time to my server, and then retrieve it back; I think I can't manage this and It seems very cumbersome to me. I just dreamt a couple of code which returns a server time residing on a webpage to me. :)

Comment: @KeremAytaç (a) What is your app trying to accomplish and (b) is there a server component to it?

Comment: My application tries to get a beginning time and start for a task; when user ended this task manually, App. will get an ending time also, and calculate the substraction of beginning and ending times. And I don't want user to change this time substraction by changing his phone time, IF I USE, datetime.now ...

Comment: I just want to get real time on the world. No matter phone's time, or anything. Just want to get real time on the world, so I think I can retrieve this on a web page, maybe on windows servers etc. If there is no way to do that, I will parse google's time as @evanmcdonnal says

Comment: @KeremAytaç:  (b) Is there a server component?  (or is this entirely on the phone?)

Comment: @KeremAytaç What do you mean by 'windows servers'? Microsoft doesn't have servers that which you can just ask for the current time (at least not in a direct manner).

Comment: I just mean, windows must be keeping a real and high accuracy world time in somewhere on their servers, and maybe we can retrieve it somehow. @AustinSalonen No it's just a phone application. There is no server classes or components in it.

Comment: @KeremAytaç:  If it's entirely limited to the phone itself, then why does this even matter?  Who cares if they change the time?

Comment: What would you do If your boss wants you to make a high accuracy world time application? It simply shows the world time (as GMT) syncronised via Internet.

Comment: @AustinSalonen Because I will post this successful task to facebook when the user manages this task within 5 minutes. I don't want user to post cheated results to facebook. He must success this within 5 mins.

Comment: @KeremAytaç:  You should alter your question with that because that matters.

Comment: @AustinSalonen So what do you think about this issue? Is there any way to retrieve a real world time from internet into my application?

Comment: I would explore the Facebook API and see if there's a way it can manage that for you.

Comment: @AustinSalonen Forget facebook :) I ve just given an example to explain why I want the real time into my application. My problem is so basic, I just want to return a real world time. How can I do this?

Comment: @KeremAytaç: I go back to my original point -- if time matters, something outside of the client's ecosystem must control it.